# Not able to read /proc/[pid]/stat in unix showing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to read /proc/[pid]/stat in ubuntu UNIX.But the output comes as segmentation fault. I am passing pid to get_usage().

```
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

struct pstat {
long unsigned int utime_ticks;
long int cutime_ticks;
long unsigned int stime_ticks;
long int cstime_ticks;
long unsigned int vsize; // virtual memory size in bytes
long unsigned int rss; //Resident  Set  Size in bytes

long unsigned int cpu_total_time;
 };

 void main(){
  int pid_t; 
  struct pstat *result;
  pid_t = getpid();
  get_usage(pid_t,result);
   }
 int get_usage(const pid_t pid, struct pstat* result) {

printf("%d",pid);
char pid_s[20];
snprintf(pid_s, sizeof(pid_s), "%d", pid);
char stat_filepath[30] = "/proc/"; 

strncat(stat_filepath, pid_s,sizeof(stat_filepath) - strlen(stat_filepath) -1);

strncat(stat_filepath, "/stat", sizeof(stat_filepath) -strlen(stat_filepath) -1);
printf("%s",stat_filepath);

FILE *fpstat = fopen(stat_filepath, "r");

if (fpstat == NULL) {
    perror("FOPEN ERROR ");
    return -1;
}

FILE *fstat = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
if (fstat == NULL) {
    perror("FOPEN ERROR ");
    fclose(fstat);
    return -1;
}


//read values from /proc/pid/stat
bzero(result, sizeof(struct pstat));
long int rss;
if (fscanf(fpstat, "%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*u %*u %*u %*u %lu"
            "%lu %ld %ld %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %lu %ld",
            &result->utime_ticks, &result->stime_ticks,
            &result->cutime_ticks, &result->cstime_ticks, &result->vsize,
            &rss) == EOF) {
    fclose(fpstat);
    return -1;
}
fclose(fpstat);
result->rss = rss * getpagesize();

//read+calc cpu total time from /proc/stat
long unsigned int cpu_time[10];
bzero(cpu_time, sizeof(cpu_time));
if (fscanf(fstat, "%*s %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu",
            &cpu_time[0], &cpu_time[1], &cpu_time[2], &cpu_time[3],
            &cpu_time[4], &cpu_time[5], &cpu_time[6], &cpu_time[7],
            &cpu_time[8], &cpu_time[9]) == EOF) {
    fclose(fstat);
    return -1;
}

fclose(fstat);

for(int i=0; i < 10;i++)
    result->cpu_total_time += cpu_time[i];

return 0;
  }
```

Output:

```
    Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Code source:https://github.com/fho/code_snippets/blob/master/c/getusage.c

Comment: specify your output and where you get an error exactly

Comment: Your effort to use `strncat` as safe replacement to `strcat` is creditable, but makes your code very hard to read. You are pretty safe here because your input value ranges are well known in this case. The code has no obvious errors. Are you sure you are actually handing in a pointer to a properly allocated `struct pstat` as `result`?

Comment: Actually,for now I am just executing this much code and not storing result. Because with this code I am not able open /proc/[pid]/stat file

Comment: @greenshade I have added the output

Comment: @Vipin so what are you passing as result argument?

Comment: @Vipin We can't see your code *executing anything*. You excluded the important parts. I'm pretty sure the file is actually opened properly.

Comment: The code of `get_usage` function works well for me. I have no problem getting and printing data from `/proc/<pid>/stat` and `/proc/stat` files. Perhaps the problem is in another section of code

Comment: @red0ct I have edited the code.

Comment: Compile and link with the -g flag.  Then when you get a core dump use: gdb programname corefile    Then use the command "where" to see exactly where it died.  Also "print variablename" is useful.

Comment: @John Hascall I did what u said. segmentation fault is coming because of fscanf().but I don't know what is wrong

Comment: See T. Johnson's answer.

Comment: "This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of bzero()."

Answer (score 2):

In `get_usage()` you are calling `bzero()` and then trying to `fscanf()` using a variable called `result` which was never allocated memory.

You need to make the result variable in your `main()` function be `struct stat result` and pass `&result` to the `get_usage()` function.

Comment: I got it.Thank you